# Kmeans for image clustering

Tags: opencv, k-means

I am new to image processing and I am using k-means for clustering for my assignment. I am having an issue where my friend told me that to use k-mean in opencv, we need to only pass the color of the object of interest and not the whole image.

This has confused me as I am not sure how to obtain the color composition before apply kmeans. Sorry about my English, I would give an example. I have a picture with several colors and lets say I want to obtain the blue cluster which is a car. So does it means that I need to pass only the color blue to the kmeans.

Maybe I am totally wrong in this since I am unsure and i have been struggling for several days now. I think I need thorough explanation from some expert whom i think i will get it here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Tnis question is very vague. Can you please provide a complete example? Like what function you are trying to call? What is your input? Your desired result?

Comment: I am sorry about that. I have a image or a blue car with white and red back ground. I want to apply kmeans to the image to learn how the kmeans on opencv works before I use it on my project. Currently I have implemented the following function kmeans(sample,clusterCount,label,TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,0.0001,10000),attempt,KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,center); 

My friend told me that in opencv k-means we cannot pass the whole image but the part of the image we interested in. My confusion is do we have to only pass the pixel values of blue from my image into the above function

Comment: http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/12/k-means-clustering-1-basic-understanding.html     http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2013/01/k-means-clustering-3-working-with-opencv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to put you in the right direction, below are some hints:

1. you will pass all the pixels to k-means alongwith the desired number of clusters (or groups) to find
2. k-means will process you data and will cluster you data in the specified number of clusters
3. you will take the pixels in blue cluster (e.g.) to do what you want to do.

I hope this will help ;)

Comment: thank you for clear explanation. That ease my confusion. Thanks alot